# Where to modify the logic that calculates the height of a collapsible fieldset?

Tags: forms

I'm not sure if this is a theme issue, but I continually get my collapsible fieldsets being 1-2 scanlines too short, causing scroll bars to appear.

This project has heavy use of FAPI, sometimes with collapsible fieldsets inside other collapsible fieldsets, and the vertical scroll bars are eating too much page real estate.

I'm using an unmodified version of Fusion Starter theme, if that helps. And, I'm not a themer, but can usually get by.

I would be perfectly happy modifying the PHP or JavaScript code doing this calculation, if I just knew where it is.

Comment: Did you try changing the used theme, and set (for example) Garland?

Comment: Just tried several different themes - Garland, Minelli & Bluemarine and they all exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: As far as I can remember, there isn't any JavaScript code calculating the field set size.

Comment: I just had a look at the site in Google Chrome - it looks correct, without the scrollbars. I've been using Firefox3 and just tried Firefox4 - both exhibit the problem. Just now testing Safari, and the problem is not there, no scrollbars. AND switching over to my PC: Firefox3 - no scrollbars, IE8 - no scrollbars. Well... looks like its a browser bug. Meaning the solution is either ignore (best) or detect the client browser and adjust fieldset-wrapper height via javascript - ugh.

Comment: I actually had the same problem for a module I was developing, with scroll bars appearing in a field set contained in another field set. At that time, I didn't do anything for that. I didn't verify if the scroll bar were present only in a browser. I am glad I didn't implement any workaround. **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it can't be solved by CSS? Try adding some padding.

Comment: I'd be added padding individually for each fieldset - there ought to be a central place to correct this.

Comment: There isn't a .fieldset-wrapper?

Comment: actually, its the .fieldset-wrapper that's getting the scrollbars. I'm thinking that the fieldset is too short, causing the scrollbars, but it could just as easily be the fieldset-wrapper that is too short. Either way, I still don't know how to fix. Looking at the markup in firebug, it is the fieldset-wrapper that needs a height adjustment, but I don't want to make individual markup adjustments in my CSS for every fieldset-wrapper - that's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I also took a look at collapsible.js inside the misc folder, and it looks like it's doing some height calculations. It even seems to have a handy 'fudge' variable, but making modifications to the value of 'fudge' don't seem to make any visible difference to the fieldsets or their wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean but try setting the [#rows](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#rows) attribute. I use something close to this

```
<?php
$form['description'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Description'),
  '#default_value' => $text,
  '#rows' => count(explode("\n", $text)),
);
?>
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but according to http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6 the '#rows' attribute is not honored by fieldsets. I have sets of text fields, option widgets and buttons inside these fieldsets, and they get a scrollbar on the right edge of the fieldset box containing them all.